# Popover view not resizeable with storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopover

I want to show popover when i push to the button in iPad application. But popover is not resizeabl. i tried freeform size , make width and height 200px in storyboard. In order to understand differencies I make width and height 50 px but size has not changed yet. Popover show is working only one size.

How can I fix this resize problem ?

Thanks in replies.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(yourWidth, yourHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks. but i try size property in storyboard. i watched tutorial in youtube.(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5XFMpXLwZQ) I'm doing the same , but it is not.

Comment: Are you setting the values at Simulated sizes in the attribute inspector?

Comment: ok..My experience was the superview or the controller from which the segue is assigned should also be resized... I think if you can show your storyboard it helps to reach the problem and find a solution. plz share the storyboard picture if possible

Comment: @fozoglu i tried the same video and it is working from me.if possible please provide screenshot for attribute inspector.

Comment: it is size inspector, if possible attributes inspector.

Comment: have u set explicit content size from attributes inspector.

Comment: @DheerajSingh http://i.imgur.com/hDRbJ1H.png i checked set explicit size but my app is crashed. console log : "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/el3JQzf.png and http://i.imgur.com/yLbcZs5.png same setting getting correct output.Uncheck your explicit size.

Comment: are u using any programmatic code to set popover size.

Comment: @DheerajSingh i try new simple app.Firstly i set explicit content size and than run app no problem. thanks .